# In which scenario Object from driver node is serialized and sent to workers node in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

let's say I declare a variable and I use it inside map/filter function in spark. does my above declared variable is each time sent from driver to worker for each operation on values of map/filter.

Does my ***helloVariable*** is sent to worker node for each values of consumerRecords ? if so how to avoid it ?

```
String helloVariable = "hello testing"; //or some config/json object
JavaDStream<String> javaDStream = consumerRecordJavaInputDStream.map(
    consumerRecord -> {
     return consumerRecord.value()+" --- "+helloVariable;
    } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. When you normally pass functions to Spark, such as a map() or a filter(), this functions can use variables defined outside them in the driver program, but each task running on the cluster gets a new copy of each variable (using serialization and sending by network), and updates from these copies are not propagated back to the driver.
So the common case for this scenario is to use **broadcast variables**.
Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks. If you are interested in the broadcasting mechanism, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40694867/3842076) you can read a very good short explanation.
According to the Spark documentation, this process can be graphically shown like this:

[image: Broadcast variable]

Broadcast variables can be used, for example, to give every node a copy of a large dataset (for example, a dictionary with a list of keywords) in an efficient manner. Spark also attempts to distribute broadcast variables using efficient broadcast algorithms to reduce communication cost.

So in your case your code might look like this:

```
Broadcast<String> broadcastVar = sc.broadcast("hello testing");
JavaDStream<String> javaDStream = consumerRecordJavaInputDStream.map(
    consumerRecord -> {
         return consumerRecord.value() + " --- " + broadcastVar.value();
    });
```