# How can I improve display()'s performance in databricks?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I separated the subquery with as into each data frame.

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ranked_goods_query = """
select  ...
  """

all_goods_no_query = """
SELECT ...
"""

all_goods_no_df = read_from_redshift(all_goods_no_query)

ranked_goods_df = read_from_redshift(ranked_goods_query)

given_date = datetime.strptime("2014-06-12", "%Y-%m-%d").date()
today = datetime.today().date()

date_range = [given_date + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((today - given_date).days + 1)]
date_df = spark.createDataFrame([(date,) for date in date_range], ["date"])

filtered_date_df = date_df.select(
    F.date_format(F.col("date"), "yyyy-MM").alias("char_date")
).dropDuplicates().orderBy("char_date")

filtered_date_partitioned = filtered_date_df.repartition(2, "char_date")

all_combinations_df = all_goods_no_df.crossJoin(filtered_date_partitioned.hint("broadcast"))


gl_goods_query = """
select ...
"""

gl_goods_df = read_from_redshift(gl_goods_query)

goods_df = read_table_from_redshift("goods").select("goods_no", "DEF_GOODS_NM")


window_spec = (
    Window.partitionBy("goods_no")
    .orderBy("char_date")
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
)

all_combinations_df_partitioned = F.broadcast(all_combinations_df.repartition(4, "goods_no"))
ranked_goods_partitioned = ranked_goods_df.repartition(8, "goods_no")


joined_df = (
    all_combinations_df_partitioned.join(
        ranked_goods_partitioned.hint("broadcast"),
        ["char_date", "goods_no"],
        "left_outer",
    )
    .join(gl_goods_df.hint("broadcast"), "goods_no", "left_outer")
    .join(goods_df.hint("broadcast"), "goods_no", "left_outer")
    .withColumn(
        "CUMULATIVE_QTY",
        F.sum(F.coalesce(F.col("sqty"), F.lit(0))).over(window_spec),
    )
    .select(
        "char_date",
        "goods_no",
        F.when(F.col("goods_nm").isNotNull(), F.col("goods_nm"))
        .otherwise(F.col("DEF_GOODS_NM"))
        .alias("GOODS_NM"),
        "CUMULATIVE_QTY",
    )
    .orderBy("char_date", "goods_no")
)
```

It takes about 1.8 seconds to get here.

But...

```
joined_df.display()
```

As soon as you run that line, there are about nine spark jobs, so it takes 20 seconds to display()

I want to reduce the spark work on display() here and improve performance

enter image description here

Looking at DAG Visualization and Summer Metrics, I suspect it's this section, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is using using [Lazy Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) .
Nothing will be computed until an action or transformation is triggered.

i.e. when you call `joined_df.display()` only then spark will actually start doing any work. All your code before adds up to the `Spark Query Plan`, which is very fast. Only when `display()` is called your query plan is realized and put into action.

FYI: here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685469/in-spark-how-does-broadcast-work) elaborating broadcasted variables are also lazy

Comment: Then, we proceeded to change sql consisting of with ~ as syntax into join between data frames. What are some ways to improve performance at this time?
Previously, sql consisting of with ~ as takes 19 seconds at first, then about 4 seconds after.
Please understand that this is my first time using Spark.

Comment: Are you running localhost or on databricks/cluster

Comment: Also on small datasets things can very and spark may also do some caching. If you go to bigger data you should see more consistent results

Comment: I am running on databricks/cluster. This code is in my databricks's notebook.

1. ranked_goods_df's count is 270,516. 
2. all_combinations_df's count is 11,100
3. gl_goods_df's count is 94,952
4. goods_df's count is 94,952